# Map.values() not working flutter dart . Values filed is not showing and how can I iterate through?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  likes.values.forEach((val) {
      if (val == true) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }
```

**values.foreach is not showing in dart flutter**

Comment: could you share how `likes` map looks like in the debugger?

Comment: I am new to Flutter I am Watching Tutorial from udemy . His code is working but mine is not

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `values filed is not showing` but if it's about the count not being higher than 0, then the map appears to be empty. I can't help you fix that since I don't see the rest of your code

Comment: Inside the Buildcontext method values option is showing but outside it is not showing.

Comment: I posted full code

Comment: the build method returns `null` child inside `Container`, did you forgot to paste it? I mean, how do you check if `values option is showing`

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the type for the field before accessing its properties. You did not mention the type as Map in `getLikesCounts` method `likes` parameter. So, it takes default type as dynamic. If you mention the type, the intelligent will show their properties.

```dart
  int getLikeCounts(Map? likes) {
    //if no likes, return 0
    if (likes == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    //if the key is explictly set to true, add like
    int count = 0;
    likes.values.forEach((val) {
      if (val == true) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }
```

Comment: Okay brother. If it's working, you can approve the answer. It will be helpful to someone who has the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Ok brother, Just leave it ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Post extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? postId;
  final String? ownerId;
  final String? username;
  final String? location;
  final String? description;
  final String? mediaUrl;
  final dynamic likes;
  Post(
      {required this.postId,
      required this.ownerId,
      required this.username,
      required this.location,
      required this.description,
      required this.mediaUrl,
      required this.likes});

  factory Post.fromDocument(dynamic doc) {
    return Post(
      postId: doc['postId'],
      ownerId: doc['ownerId'],
      username: doc['username'],
      location: doc['location'],
      description: doc['description'],
      mediaUrl: doc['mediaUrl'],
      likes: doc['likes'],
    );
  }
  int getLikeCounts(likes) {
    //if no likes, return 0
    if (likes == null) {
      return 0;
    }
    //if the key is explictly set to true, add like
    int count = 0;
    likes.values.forEach((val) {
      if (val == true) {
        count += 1;
      }
    });
    return count;
  }

  @override
  _PostState createState() => _PostState(
      postId: this.postId,
      ownerId: this.ownerId,
      username: this.username,
      location: this.location,
      description: this.description,
      mediaUrl: this.mediaUrl,
      likes: this.likes,
      likeCount: getLikeCounts(this.likes));
}

class _PostState extends State<Post> {
  final String? postId;
  final String? ownerId;
  final String? username;
  final String? location;
  final String? description;
  final String? mediaUrl;
  int? likeCount;
  final Map? likes;

  _PostState({
    required this.postId,
    required this.ownerId,
    required this.username,
    required this.location,
    required this.description,
    required this.mediaUrl,
    required Map this.likes,
    required this.likeCount,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: null,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Heres the Full Code .

Comment: Instead of posting the code in an answer, could place it in the question? There should be an `edit` button below the tags